# CJuiDatePicker year/year-month/year-month-day selection

Tags: javascript, yii, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have project on Yii and there is a task to choose date from **juidatepicker** widget. But it must be in three different types as **year/year-month/year-month-day**. How i can modify datepicker and choose date in that three type in one datepicker ? I am not stong in JS and sorry for my english

Comment: explain your problem and show us what have you tried ?

Comment: For now this date picker choose date in format year-month-day. I listed a lot of forums and the most close decision is to put one more datepicker and to set it dateformat to -year-month-, and one more and set it dateformat to -year-. But i need to choose date in this three format in one date picker. One more deciscion(i guess) is  to write some JS function on selection month/year dropdowns, than can format date from selected month/year. But i guess it should not work as i want

Comment: You can use hidden fields and display format options.

Comment: Can you tell more about this ?

Comment: I can't imagine what you want. What couldn't above 3 options of datepicket achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set all three Datepickers and `hide()`/`show()` them depending on your needs (with a dropdown or something like that..).

You can also try to `append()` to the datepicker a bar menu with three buttons to switch between the modes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`CJuiDatePicker` implements [jQuery UI Datepicker Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), so you can set [`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) property. See example how to change it dynamically:

```
<p>Please, select date format
<ul>
    <li><input type="radio" name="dateFormat" value="yy" checked="checked">yy</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="dateFormat" value="yy-mm">yy-mm</li>
    <li><input type="radio" name="dateFormat" value="yy-mm-dd">yy-mm-dd</li>
</ul>
<p>Date <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker">

<script>
    var dp = $('#datepicker');
    var dateFormat = "yy";
    dp.datepicker({dateFormat:dateFormat});
    $(':radio[name="dateFormat"]').change(function(){
        dp.datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $(this).val() );
    });
</script>
```